# Why is my Fragment animation not played when expected?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the following code to add a fragment to an activity. It slides in from the bottom when the user clicks on a button, and it should slide out to the bottom when she presses back. To do this I implement `setCustomAnimation(int, out, popEnter, popExit)`. [According to the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), the `popExit` animation is played on back pressed.

The slide in part works fine, but the fragment just disappears from the screen on back pressed instead of playing the `popExit` anim.

The next time the user presses the button (`addFragment` is called) to show the fragment, the slide out (`popExit`) animation will be played before the slide in anim. **Any idea why?**

```
public void addFragment(Fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom,R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

}

Comment: I wrote a simple application to reproduce this problem, but it works fine for me. Here you can a [source code](http://pastebin.com/PgArse0N). Can you make a simple fully working example affected by the problem?

Comment: I observe the same behavior, but my fragment is above another fragment which view is SurfaceView.